# org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot find class in classpath: CheckAndSubmitSFOAutomaticLeversToQTest

Tags: java, eclipse, testng, testcase

I am getting the above error while running the test case.

I have tried eclipse oxygen/ sts.4.2.0 on both same issue is coming ,also added a testng zip file, not downloaded from the marketplace due to some company firewall issue.

My project is not a maven project. I have already looked into jars there is no duplicate jar with different versions in the build path.

What else I am missing? I think this might be due to some conflicting jars but I am unable to find out which jars are causing issue, attaching screenshot of my buildpath.

Comment: Eclispe Oxygen is too old. There is most likely a dependency compiled with at least Java 11 (which is the latest LTS release) involved, and Eclipse Oxygen is even older.

Comment: I can try with this . but the project is also very old .. it's legacy project

Comment: Tried STS 4.2as well. same issue is coming .

Comment: @Loren are you getting the error for any simple test case? or just for the `CheckAndSubmitSFOAutomaticLeversToQTest` ?

Comment: @Loren Also could you explain how you are using the `testng.zip` file?

Comment: The error got resolved by adding folders from project in buildpath->source.